# Integrating Kekule.js into React App Build with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Dear community!

So I have set-up a react app in which helps people related with chemistry publish their works, and for that I have found a library called Kekule.js [Here it is](https://partridgejiang.github.io/Kekule.js/)

As I said I use typescript which now demands that I define types for the library I use, but the library is not in the NPM, neither can I find @types/kekule.js or something similar.

As there are really a whole lot of functions in the library I wonder if anyone can help me with getting a fast way of defining types for typscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kekule.js indeed can't be found on NPM, at least I couldn't

Assuming, You use react, the only way would be to create a file, if not exists already and declare Your types there.

in `index.d.ts` (d stands for 'definitions')
add `declare module "your-module-without-types"`

Also see [Typescript Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Comment: Is there any automatic way to generate types for the functions in library? This requires lots of manual work.

Comment: Well, I have not seen anything like that, but searching for something like that might help. I mean there are auto JSDoc generators, right? But to be honest, it is not that bad considering You have to define types only when You use a certain function or object, and after defining them once, certainly, they can be reused in some way.